# $min output not showing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

i seem to have a problem in showing the output for $min. I want to get the output that shows the minimum value for the air_Temp with the machine Id showing as well. But right now, the output is showing me "Record not found".

```
db.contact.aggregate([{$group : {machine_Id : "$machine_Id", air_Temp : {$min : "$likes"}}}], function(err, meibanlist){
  if (err || !meibanlist) console.log ("Record not found");
  else meibanlist.forEach (function(machine_Id){
    console.log(machine_Id);

  });
});
```

Comment: share one of the stored documents

Comment: I think you need an `_id` field in `$group` expression

Comment: isnt _id and machine_Id the same though?

Comment: No they are not, `_id` field is mandatory in `$group` stage as mentioned [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.contact.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$machine_Id", air_Temp : {$min : "$likes"}}}], function(err, meibanlist){
  if (err) console.log ("error >>>",err);
  else{
    if(!meibanlist) console.log("record not found);
      meibanlist.forEach (function(machine_Id){
        console.log(machine_Id);
      });
  });
```